# what does java.util.Arrays$ArrayList mean?

Tags: java, arraylist

I keep getting the following error message

```
File: C:\Users\jiangbuyun\Desktop\p5\p5pack\P5Tests.java  [line: 1084]
Failure: java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList<[A:X, B:X, C:X]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[A:X, B:X, C:X]>
```

I have a class called circuit. Here are some fields.

```
private List<Contact> inputs, outputs;
private List<Wire> innerWires;
```

and this is the method how I get inputs

```
public void parseContactsLine(String line){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
    int i=0; //token's position
    while (! sc.hasNext("->")){
      Wire w = new Wire (sc.next());
      innerWires.add(w);
      Contact c = new Contact(innerWires.get(i),innerWires.get(i),true);
      inputs.add(c);
      i++;
    }
```

My test case:

```
public void circuit_parseContactsLine1(){
    List<Contact> empty = Arrays.asList(new Contact[]{});
    assertEquals(empty, vanillaCircuit.getInputs());
    assertEquals(empty, vanillaCircuit.getOutputs());
    List<Contact> ins = Arrays.asList(new Contact[]{
      new Contact(new Wire("A"), new Wire("A"), true),
        new Contact(new Wire("B"), new Wire("B"), true),
        new Contact(new Wire("C"), new Wire("C"), true)}
    );
    List<Contact> outs = Arrays.asList(new Contact[]{
      new Contact(new Wire("D"), new Wire("D"), false)}
    );

    vanillaCircuit.parseContactsLine("A B C -> D");
    assertEquals(ins , vanillaCircuit.getInputs ());
    assertEquals(outs, vanillaCircuit.getOutputs());
  }
```

It seems this error arises from the comparison between ArrayList and List. The test case uses Array.asList() to get "inputs", and my method returns an arraylist as well. Can anyone explain to me what java.util.Arrays$ArrayList mean?

The error when I am trying input.add(Arrays.asList(c));

```
File: C:\Users\jiangbuyun\Desktop\p5\p5pack\Circuit.java  [line: 48]
Error: no suitable method found for add(java.util.List<Contact>)
    method java.util.Collection.add(Contact) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.List<T> conforms to Contact)
    method java.util.List.add(Contact) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that java.util.List<T> conforms to Contact)
```

Answer (score 7):

`java.util.Arrays$ArrayList` is a nested class inside the `Arrays` class that implements the `List` interface. This implementation has a fixed length and is backed by an array.

The method `Arrays.asList` returns an instance of this class.

Comment: So the test case actually returns this nested class thing, while my method returns an arraylist?

Comment: In my method, I tried to do things like inputs.add(Arrays.asList(c)), but I cant even compile.

Comment: @user4593157 I don't see where you are creating an instance of java.util.ArrayList, but if `vanillaCircuit.getInputs ()` returns an instance of java.util.ArrayList, then yes.

Comment: @user4593157 Where is this `inputs.add(Arrays.asList(c))` code that doesn't compile? It would help to see it in its context.

Comment: I have posted the error message when using asList(). Would you take a look at it? Thanks

Comment: @user4593157 `add` can only add a single element to the List. You are trying to add a List to a List. Instead of `input.add(Arrays.asList(c))`, try `input.addAll(Arrays.asList(c))`.

Comment: It compiles, but still gives the Arrays$ArrayList error. Well, I will check through all my codes. Thank you though.